# How to check if element of array contains any value or not

Tags: java, arrays

This is a program which is saving String as a key and number of counts in String array. But 
as shown in condition clause (//CONDITION) , i am unable to check weather an element of array contains any value or not?

I know that it throws an exception "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" because it cant allocate memory to unspecified element. I was trying to do "nextString.equals(arrays[i+1])" , it doesn't work.

Please specify any condition i can use.

```
public void mapExample() {
     String text = "text good text good text";
     String[] arrays = text.split(" ");
     Arrays.sort(arrays);
     for(String array :arrays ){
     System.out.println(array);
     }
         int Count=0;
         String thisSring = "";
         String nextString="";
         TreeMap<String,Integer> mapper = new TreeMap<String , Integer>();
         for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;++i){
             thisSring = arrays[i];
             Count++;
             nextString = arrays[i+1];
             if(!thisSring.equals(nextString)){
                 mapper.put(thisSring, Count);
             }


             if(//CONDITION){
                 mapper.put(thisSring, Count);
             }
         }



        Set s = mapper.entrySet();
            Iterator iter = s.iterator();
            if(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iter.next());
            Map.Entry map = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            System.out.println( "Key" + " " + map.getKey());
            System.out.println("Value" + " " + map.getValue());
        }
     }
     }
```

Comment: why not just check if its in the map?

Comment: An element of an array always contains a value.  Of course, sometimes that value is `null`, but that's a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is earlier then you think,

```
for(int i=0;i<arrays.length - 1;++i){   // Add a "- 1" because,
  thisSring = arrays[i];
  Count++;
  nextString = arrays[i+1];             // this will exceed the array length otherwise.
  if(!thisSring.equals(nextString)){
    mapper.put(thisSring, Count);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...equals(String.valueOf(nextString))
```

let me explain, If you were to perform an equals comparison of two String objects, the ".equals" function checks if the objects are equal, not the value of the object. Solve this by using ".valueOf()"

Secondly, You have an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". This is often caused by what is called an off-by-one error. Move "Count++;" to the end of the for loop, and I think that will prevent it from throwing that exception.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;++i){
```

to:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrays.length-1;++i){
```

because you're running with `i+1`

Second, since you're using `count++` - you are not really counting anything.
You have to check if the string is not already in the TreeMap, if it is - update the count to be:

```
mapper.get(thisSring) + 1
```

and if it isn't there, create a new item with `count = 1`:

```
 String thisSring = "";
 String nextString="";
 TreeMap<String,Integer> mapper = new TreeMap<String , Integer>();
 for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;++i){
     thisSring = arrays[i];
     nextString = arrays[i+1];
     if(mapper.get(thisString) != null){
         mapper.put(thisSring, mapper.get(thisString) + 1);
     }
     else {
         mapper.put(thisSring, 1);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change for loop:

```
for (int i =0;i<arrays.length;i++) {
```

To

```
for (int i =0;i<arrays.length-1;i++) {
```

find the following code:

```
for (int i =0;i<arrays.length-1;i++) {
         thisString = arrays[i];
         count++;
         nextString = arrays[i+1];
         if(!thisString.equals(nextString)){
             mapper.put(thisString, count);
         }

         if (i<arrays.length-2) {
             mapper.put(thisString, count);
         }

}
```